# jQuery .fadeIn() makes an element slide from the bottom upon sidebar expansion

Tags: jquery, css

I have an issue with my sidebar. I want to hide the logo title when the sidebar is collapsed and show when the sidebar is expanded. Now I'm using jQuery's fade in and fade out effect to achieve this. However, upon expanding the sidebar, the menu item `HOME` slides up from the bottom, which doesn't look good.

I'm assuming that the logo title is taking up space above `HOME` and when the sidebar toggle button is pressed, the title moves to the top beside the logo and `HOME` slides up.

How can I achieve a smooth hide/show effect upon collapsing/expanding the sidebar without having an impact on other elements?

Here's the link to the full code with the actual problem: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/zakero/pen/LYNEPKa)

Here's a sample code which I tried:

HTML

```
<nav id="sidebar" class="active">
    <h1>
       <a href="index.html" class="logo"><span class="fas fa-globe-americas"></span> <span class="logo-title">villa</span></a>
     </h1>

     <ul class="list-unstyled components mb-5">
          <li>
            <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-home"></span> Home</a>
          </li>
     </ul>
</nav>
```

jQUery

```
(function($) {

    "use strict";

    $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {

      $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');

      if($('#sidebar').hasClass('active')) {
        $('#sidebar .logo .logo-title').fadeOut(1);
      }else{
        $('#sidebar .logo .logo-title').fadeIn(1000);
      }

    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I am really sorry, I read your question wrong earlier. Do you want to hide/show "Home" text in span on sidebar collision/expansion?

Comment: No. I want to hide show the logo title ```villa``` on sidebar collapse/expanse. Please go to the codepen and press the sidebar hamburger button. You will see the ```HOME``` text slides up from the bottom on sidebar expansion.

Comment: So you don't want `HOME` text to move from its place, is it?

Comment: Yes. You're right!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the `HOME` as it is in collapsed form then, the simplest approach is to wrap it in a p tag and add bootstrap class `m-0` to remove margins :

```
<ul class="list-unstyled components mb-5">
  <li>
    <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-home"></span> <p class="m-0">Home</p></a>
  </li>          
</ul>
```

Comment: Same issue mate. I guess it's not possible. :(

Comment: I tried the code several times, not just on codepen but codeply as well. Try doing it after clearing cache. Maybe it'll work. It's definitely possible.

Comment: @Zak check these two links:

https://www.linkpicture.com/q/Annotation-2020-08-06-203751.png

https://www.linkpicture.com/q/new_1.png